# how to merge two or more java project in eclipse via svn

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, merge

I am working in one java project and my colleague working in another java project in different machine.We store our both project in server via SVN.Question is how to merge my project and colleague project because both project works together as a war file???how to merge using SVN and server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge your code with that of your colleague, you should both be committing the code into the same SVN repository.

If you're both committing to the same branch, then you just need to use `Team -> Synchronize` to get the latest code from the repository.

If you're both committing to different branches, then you need to merge from your colleague's branch to your branch (or vice versa). To do this, make sure your have the latest code from your branch - use `Team->Synchronize` - and then use `Team->Merge` to select your colleague's branch as the source of the merge. Then resolve any conflicts, and commit your change.

Comment: In that case, assuming you've got an SVN plugin installed in Eclipse, `Team->Synchronize` should be sufficient.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Have you checked out the code using the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: question is my project name are different and colleague project name are different so how to merge both project in one project and we access together in same project via svn?

Comment: You need to add more details about exactly what you are doing, preferably with some examples.

Comment: Me and my colleague working in one project .I am creating some jsp pages and my colleague creating another pages.How to merge our pages that are works together?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15044/discussion-between-shubhanshu-and-rajesh-j-advani)